# Confused with how two or more always block work in verilog module?

Tags: verilog

Suppose I have got two always block in the verilog module. Do these two block work concurrently?

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
  //some code
 end

always @(Input1 or Input2) begin
  //some logic
end
```

I knew the data inside them executed in the sequential manner. How two blocks get executed??? That's the question that is troubling view. I need to have a big picture of it.

Comment: is simulation in xlink is possible only as the logic level? can we view it as the better and at the more feasible level? if they run concurrently, do both block completes in one clock cycle or do it take longer number of clock cycle?

Comment: What is 'the better and at the more feasible level'? I consider verilog to have 3 levels. **Behavioural** mainly used for testbenches but also models of blocks. **RTL** The synthesizable part, that can be turned in to hardware. **Gate Level** the output from synthesis describing your design using logic gates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Verilog is a HDL (Hardware Description Language), hardware can be designed with many parallel circuits therefore a simulator for this must be able to simulate the parallelism of the design.

The Verilog language is not meant to be used like other concurrent language like Scala and GO*.

Verilog produces all concurrent results on **timesteps**, which could be set to something like 1 picosecond. **Delta** cycles (between timesteps) are used to compute combinatorial sections and resolve feedback.

`always @(posedge clk)` blocks only have to be evaluated when there is a positive edge on the clk.
`always @*` or with a manual senstivity list (which is no longer recommended) have to be evaluated when a right hand argument or an input to an if/case statement changes.

For example

```
// Block 1
always @* begin //Sensitivity list would be 'Input1, Input2'
  intermediate = Input1 + Input2;
end

// Block 2
always @* begin //Sensitivity list would be 'intermediate'
  output1 = intermediate >> 1; // divide by 2
end
```

When Input1 or Input2 change Block 1 will be scheduled for evaluation in the next delta cycle, which will in turn cause Block 2 to be scheduled for evaluation in the delta cycle after that. And the result of `intermediate` and `output1` will appear on the next timestep.

More can be read about this in the Language Reference Manual (LRM) **[SystemVerilog IEEE 1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf) Section 4. Scheduling semantics**.

When programming an FPGA which is programmable logic circuit, not a CPU, it will configure parallel blocks of hardware.

*I do not have experience in either of these, they just seem like they are popular language for parallel computing. If this is wrong or there are better examples please edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

Its easier to think of them as two threads that are always running.

Comment: If it is, how the fpga board manages the same logic. Does it switches as it is in thread or different block acts simulatneously to perform the activity thus present.

Answer (score 0):

```
    // please tell me the all possible results from
 module exampl(a,y);
 // case 1
 /*input a;
 wire a;
 output y;
 reg y;*/

 // case 2

/*input a;
reg a;
output y;
wire y;*/

/*this is case 3 .what is result case 3 if we use  case 1 on case 3 and case 
2 on on case 3 */

always @(posedge clk) 
begin
a=1;
end

always @(negedge clk) 
begin
a=0;
end
endmodule;
// neglect the comment line for using the either case
```